# Nginx, PHP-FPM and Memcached

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, memcached

I have Wordpress installation running on two web servers powered by Nginx. I configured Memcached on both servers and I'm using W3 total cache plugin for Memcached:

1. What's the recommended solution for multiply Memcached servers. I've configured both in  W3 plugin (192.168.1.1;11211, 192.168.1.2:11211) but I'm not sure if this a good solution in terms of performance as the cache will be stored on both servers simultaneously? Shall I configure only loopack address on each web server? How this actually works - cache is replicated on both servers in this case?
2. Could you please provide some good articles/guide how to implement chrooted environment for PHP-FPM?
3. Which PHP extension is recommended: php-pecl-memcached or php-pecl-memcache. The W3 plugin is not actually recognize php-pecl-memcached.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to memcache, it does not replicate entries between machine.  If you check their site you will see that it is a:

> distributed memory object caching system

By distributed, cache objects are distributed over your various memcaches.   Unless you are seeing very high traffic (10's millions page views/month), this will have little impact on performance and I would just leave it as you have it.

The PHP extension you want is:
http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache

In terms of PHP-FPM, see:
http://www.ewanleith.com/blog/900/10-million-hits-a-day-with-wordpress-using-a-15-server
Interesting read but in general, this has to be tuned per-blog since so most of the performance issues are caused by WP plugins and not the code itself.

Just a tip with WP, if you can move things out of plugins and into your templates, e.g. social sharing code, this is typically faster.